# Sort items of Kendocombobox

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I am using a Kendo ComboBox in my app with this code below:

```
$("#txtSetorOrigem").kendoComboBox({
    change : function (e) {
        if (this.value() && this.selectedIndex == -1) {                    
            alert('You must select a valid item');
            this.value('');
        }
    },
    filter : 'contains',
    dataTextField: "setorNome",
    dataValueField: "setorId",
    dataSource: [
        { setorNome: "bbb", setorId: 1 },
        { setorNome: "aaa", setorId: 2 },
        { setorNome: "eee", setorId: 3 },
        { setorNome: "ccc", setorId: 4 },
        { setorNome: "ddd", setorId: 5 }
    ],
    select: function(e) {
        var item = e.item;
        var text = item.text();
        $(".txtSelSetorOrigem").val(text);
        $(".txtSetorOrigem").val(text);
    }
});
```

How can I sort this datasource by items (setorNome) using kendocombobox?

aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a dojo which shows a way of doing it: [Sorting Data Source](http://dojo.telerik.com/ivIzA)

All I have done is added a sort section to the datasource like so:

```
 {
    data:[
        { setorNome: "bbb", setorId: 1 },
        { setorNome: "aaa", setorId: 2 },
        { setorNome: "eee", setorId: 3 },
        { setorNome: "ccc", setorId: 4 },
        { setorNome: "ddd", setorId: 5 }],
    sort:{field:"setorNome", dir:"asc"}
}
```

For more info on the dataSource object check this link: [Kendo DataSource Sorting](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-sort) I have linked it to the sorting section for you.

Hopefully this is what you were after. If not then let me know and I will look into another solution for you.

Comment: Does anyone know the method to sort when using BindTo instead of DataSource?